# SwiftUI: How to update child view with @Binding variable before updating state of parent view?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have a basic setup to show another view over my ContentView using the code below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var otherViewShowing: Bool = true

  var body: some View {
    if otherViewShowing {
        OtherView(amIShowing: $otherViewShowing)
    } else {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
  }
}
```

When I set the "otherViewShowing" variable to false through changing "amIShowing" in the button in OtherView, though, the view abruptly disappears and the text for "Hello, world!" is shown immediately. I'm trying to get the OtherView to play the scaling down animation before updating the ContentView to show "Hello, world!" so it's a bit smoother.

```
struct OtherView: View {
  @Binding var amIShowing: Bool
  @State private var scaleAmount: CGFloat = 1

  var body: some View {
      VStack {
          Button("Tap me") {
              withAnimation(.default) {
                  amIShowing = false
                  scaleAmount = 0
              }
          }
      }
      .scaleEffect(scaleAmount)
  }
}
```

Any thoughts on accomplishing this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you can give duration and delay for this.

**delay:** Delays the animation for 2 seconds.

**duration:** Determines the duration of the animation.

```
VStack {
    Button("Tap me") {
       withAnimation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 2).delay(2)) {
                 amIShowing = false
                 scaleAmount = 0
          }
        }
      }
      .scaleEffect(scaleAmount)
```